# How do I disable a button in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i need some help here
i want to make my edit and delete button disabled if my task status is true
here is my view for edit and delete button

```
<td><a href = "@Url.Action("Edit","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})" class= "btn mini purple"><i class = "icon-edit"></i> Edit </a></td>
<td><a href = "@Url.Action("Delete","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})" class= "btn mini black"><i class = "icon-remove"></i> Delete </a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` tag can not disabled. So, if status is false you can remove it or prevent to click:

```
@if(yourStatus.IsOk)
{
   <td><a href = "@Url.Action("Edit","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})" class= "btn mini purple"><i class = "icon-edit"></i> Edit </a></td>
   <td><a href = "@Url.Action("Delete","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})" class= "btn mini black"><i class = "icon-remove"></i> Delete </a></td>
}
else
{
   <td><a href="/" onclick="return false;" class= "btn mini purple"><i class = "icon-edit"></i> Edit </a></td>
   <td><a href="/" onclick="return false;" class= "btn mini black"><i class = "icon-remove"></i> Delete </a></td>
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,i figure out other way but seems like your answer too, i just make my button as disable class when the status is true :D

Comment: Yes you also can use disable class inside IF. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't buttons. Those are [HTML anchor elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). Anchor elements cannot be disabled in HTML alone.

It looks like you're using an old version of Bootstrap, but you didn't include this in your question. If you want to add a `disabled` class, you can do so like this:

```
<td><a href = "@Url.Action("Edit","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})"
    class= "btn mini purple @Disabled(task.Status)">
    <i class = "icon-edit"></i> Edit </a></td>
<td><a href = "@Url.Action("Delete","Task", new {id = task.TaskId})"
    class= "btn mini black @Disabled(task.Status)">
    <i class = "icon-remove"></i> Delete </a></td>

@helper Disabled(bool disable)
{
    if (disable)
    {
        @:disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: im not trying this one,but i think it will work too :D                     but i already figure out the problem,i just need to make the button become a disable class when the status is true